# .htaccess permanent redirect with query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to make a permanent redirect work. The problem is that all the examples I find seem to be to make it work the other way then what I'm looking for

```
page.php?parameter=ID
```

to

```
page/parameter/ID
```

The closes I've come to is

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} parameter=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/parameter/$1? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that this does not add the ID at the end for some reason

Please advise

Comment: Don't you want to rewrite it back ? I mean, what will `/page/parameter/xxx` serves as content ? You should serve the same content as `/page.php?parameter=xxx` equivalent, while "masking" it

Comment: I was expecting this question.
The original page has been removed and now uses the new URL structure and I want the user to be redirected to the new, correct URL to get he content that is now served by a controller, not a procedural page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} parameter=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /page/parameter/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Just a small change. You need to use `%1` instead of `$1` as that grabs the variable results. After Justin's help, I now realise there is no need for the `?` or the `NE` flag. Instead all you need is the `QSD` flag, which will discard the original query.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: `NE flag as that stops the original query from appending onto the end of the URL` ??? This is definitely not what `NE` does

Comment: `By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.` - My wording might be different, but this is what it has done by adding the `?` on the end and using the `[NE]` flag. It goes from `http://example.com/page/parameter/ID%3F?parameter=ID` to `http://example.com/page/parameter/ID`

Comment: Citation is right, but as you say, your wording is not. No matter what, I still don't understand why you're using `NE` here, it is useless. You may have some misunderstanding on that flag

Comment: Your `?` here just prevents original query string to be appended. This one will never ever be encoded. It is the start of a (new) query string, and won't ever be displayed in the url. You could also use `QSD` flag to discard the original query string

Comment: Thanks Justin, I appreciate the help. Still learning myself - but when I didn't use the `[NE]` flag, it added the original query onto the end of the URL. With it, it removes it. I'll look at these other options you've suggested.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. Yep, as I said, without `?` the original query string is automatically appended, unless you use `QSD` flag. Either you use `?` (`NE` not required here), or you use `QSD` flag

Comment: I should have figured out the `%` in stead of the `$`, but I guess I got my languages mixed up.
Thank you for clarifying the flags more in detail.